# How can I allow a user to draw a polygon with GoogleMaps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

In the web lib for google maps, there is a [DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer) which allows the user to draw either a Polygon or Circle on the map, then returns the polgon/circle attrs programmatically to the developer. I want to do the same thing in Flutter, and allow the user to draw a bounding area on the map, either with a Polygon or a Circle. What is the best way to achieve this with Flutter?

Comment: I am looking for the same sort of solution.